# How to add menu Items to toolbar in Eclipse E4

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I have an Eclipse RCP application and have added a tollbar via TrimBar->Window Trim->Toolbar->Tool Control. I have tried to add menu/ menu items using SWT Menu but it is not visible in the toolbar. Other components like buttons,labels,combo boxes are added without any problem.
Is it possible to add Menu Items to toolbar?

File   Edit   View   Tools   Window   Help   Here-The-Combobox-To-Be-Added

File/Edit/View/Tools/Window/Help are the menu items in the toolbar. And after that a combobox is to be added.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any constructors on Menu that would show the menu directly in the tool bar (or anywhere other than shells and dialogs). A drop down menu triggered from a toolbar button is, of course, possible.

Comment: Why don't you use the view menu?

Comment: @greg-449 - By toolbar button do you mean adding it as a tool item and then having a drop down menu for it?

Comment: @Stefan - I am familar with SWT Menu/MenuItems. Can you explain a little about view menu you are talking about?

Comment: I think Stefan is asking why you are not using 'Trimmed Window > Main Menu'.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't get that. I did use Trimmed Window->Main Menu for creating menu items but the thing is I need a combobox added to the end of the menu items which is not possible using Eclipse e4. So as a workaround, wanted to see if its possible to add menu items to TrimBar->Window Trim->Toolbar !!

Comment: @greg-449: correct (I thought about a view's toolbar originally but the question is about the main window's toolbar)

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to add a combo box to the trimbar.

I have tried out a progress indicator in the trim bar: Use a `ToolControl` element in the UI specification `WindowTrim->Toolbar->ToolControl`. The class given with the tool control is a POJO. Here is the beginning of my progress bindicator:

```
public class ProgressIndicator implements IProgressMonitor {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @PostConstruct
    public void createControls(final Composite parent) {
        final Group g = new Group(parent, SWT.SHADOW_ETCHED_IN | SWT.FILL);
        g.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        g.setToolTipText(Nls.INSTANCE.getString("Progressbar.tooltip"));
        this.progressBar = new ProgressBar(g, SWT.NONE );
        this.progressBar.setVisible(false);
    }
...
}
```

Comment: @Stefan- I am able to add combobox to the TrimBar without any issue. I use the same way, WindowTrim->Toolbar->ToolControl and associate a classURI file in which code to add combobox is present.                My requirement is to place the combobox next to the menu items. And this is not possible using e4 'Trimmed Window -> Main Menu -> Menu'.          So as a workaround I'm trying to do it using ToolControl.