# Toolbar item with text below the image in e4 application

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I am implementing e4 Application with Toolbar . I want both Image and text in Toolbar with text below the image How can I do this through Application.e4xml? or there are any way to achieve this.

Comment: Getting the text to appear to the right of the image is straightforward. Getting it below the image looks like you might have to do a custom toolbar renderer.

Comment: You could use a ToolControl as described in an anwer to a different question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23843488/1127492

Comment: I want text below the image there are any settings in Application.e4xml adding both

Comment: There are no such settings. There is a tag FORCE_TEXT for text right to the image and a solution with ToolControl or custom renderer.

Answer (score 0):

As Mr Covex said, add FORCE_TEXT tag in the ToolItem. This will force eclipse to display both Icon and Text (if icon uri is set).